# Python code for solving a system from LU decomposition with forward and backward substitution

Tags: python, numpy

I keep recieving an error in my code and I can't figure it out, I need to solve a system from an LU decomposition using backwards and forwards substitution. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np     

L=np.array([(1,0,0,0),(-1,1,0,0),(2,-1,1,0),(-3,2,-2,1)])
U=np.array([(2,1,-1,3),(0,1,-1,3),(0,0,-1,3),(0,0,0,3)])
b=np.array([(12,-8,21,-26)])

def forward_subs(L,b):
    y=[]
    for i in range(len(b)):
        y.append(b[i])
        for j in range(i):
            y[i]=y[i]-(L[i,j]*y[j])
        y[i]=y[i]/L[i,i]

    return y

def back_subs(U,y):
    x=np.zeros_like(y)
    for i in range(len(x),0,-1):
      x[i-1]=(y[i-1]-np.dot(U[i-1,i:],x[i:]))/U[i-1,i-1]

    return x

def solve_system_LU(L,U,b):
    y=forward_subs(L,b)
    x=back_subs(U,y)

    return x


print(solve_system_LU(L,U,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very small mistake while defining `b` you are adding an extra dimension.
So just define `b` as:

`b = np.array([12,-8,21,-26])`

And leave the remaining code as it is. Code runs without any errors and outputs

`[4.         3.         3.         1.33333333]`